# Angularjs- Upload and Update data on the page on a button click

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I am new to this technology and asking a common issue faced by many. I am updating date to database and displaying a Message like "Published Successfully" on a button click but I want the date to be updated as well on the screen. I tried adding Refresh code, but then the Published Message is not displaying but the page gets refreshed and the updated date is displayed. I am unable to perform both actions in a single Button click.
In short, I want to refresh the page automatically on button click and display updated data with message.

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="PublishManifestCtrl">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="widget-header bordered-bottom bordered-themeprimary">
            <i class="widget-icon fa fa-tasks themeprimary"></i>
            <span class="widget-caption themeprimary">Manifest Status</span>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-body">
            <form class="form-bordered" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label style="padding-left: 8px;">Manifest was last published to agents on <b>{{manifeststatus.manifestLastPublishedDate}}</b>.</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label style="padding-left: 8px;">Manifest was last updated by <b> {{manifeststatus.lastUpdatedByUser}} </b> on <b>{{manifeststatus.manifestLastedUpdatedDate}}</b>.</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-1">
                        <button id="PublishButton" class="btn btn-default shiny " ng-disabled="manifeststatus.enablePublishButton" ng-click="Save()">Publish</button>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div id="statusDivPublish" ng-show="showstatus">
                        <alert type="{{alert.type}}">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

JS Code:

```
app.controller('PublishManifestCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http) {

$scope.showstatus = false;

$http({
    url: $rootScope.WebApiURL + '/getmanifeststatus',
    method:get(),
    params: { 'foobar': new Date().getTime() }
}).
success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    var options = { year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric", hour: "numeric", minute: "numeric" };

    data.manifestLastedUpdatedDate = (new Date(data.lastUpdatedDateTime)).toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);
    data.manifestLastPublishedDate = (new Date(data.lastPublishDateTime)).toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);
    var date1 = new Date(data.lastUpdatedDateTime);
    var date2 = new Date(data.lastPublishDateTime);
    data.enablePublishButton = date2.getTime() > date1.getTime();

    $scope.manifeststatus = data;
}).
error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert('error' + status);
    // log error
}); 
$scope.Save = function (data) {
    debugger;
    $http.post($rootScope.WebApiURL + '/updatemanifeststatus');

    $scope.showstatus = true;
    $scope.alert = { type: 'success', msg: 'Published Successfully.' };
    $(".statusDivPublish").show();
    $(".statusDivPublish").remove();

)});
```

For refreshing I tried using the code as below after

```
$scope.Save = function (data) {
    debugger;
    $http.post($rootScope.WebApiURL + '/updatemanifeststatus');


//refresh
   $state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, {
         reload: true,
        inherit: false,
       notify: true
   });
```

and then the other things. But I am not sure, where I am going wrong.

Comment: You aren't sending any data in the post. Why do you have a form with no user input fields? What exactly are you trying to save?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use [ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) to execute one or more actions on the same click event. Example:

```
<button ng-click="function();otherFunction()">
```

Then, your element displaying data could stay up-to-date using [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) , refreshed by your Ajax call. Example :

Markup :

```
<p>{{ yourDate }}</p>
```

JS :

```
//.... Begin of your Ajax function

$scope.yourDate = data.yourNewDate;

//....
```

Your element content will be refresh without refresh browser.